# avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x0o

Tags: arduino, avrdude

I am trying to upload the blink sketch on my arduino.. I hav the com port sorted out( COM 11) adn installed the drivers exactly as described in the arduino.cc website. But everytime i try to upload the sketch, i get this error:

Binary sketch size: 30,724 bytes (
Binary sketch size: 30,724 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x0o

I have already tried different os( win 8 64 bit/ win 7 32/64 bit), but it still doesn't work. I am a beginner and i really need some serious help with this.. Thanx :)

Comment: You are not connected to the serial port.

Comment: Building on what FeliceM said, make sure you have selected your board and your serial port under Tools->Board and Tools->Serial Port

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I used a freeduino. What kind of board do you have? There are different kinds of Arduinoboards. The error "not in sync: resp=0x0o" means he can't recognize the Board. These are the steps that helped me:
- reinstalled the the Duino's driver
- selected the correct board in Tools->Board
- also check whether the USB-cable is working.

For more details follow these links:

[Freeduino v0.1 avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067287/freeduino-v0-1-avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00/20280003#20280003)

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=201710.msg1486452#

Comment: The problem was with the board's FTDI chip as the next arduino i tried worked perfectly fine. But the links are helpful. Thanks!

Comment: How did you check the FTDI chip?