# Freeduino v0.1 avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

Tags: arduino

I have a freeduino board, v0.1. ATMega 328

I am running Windows 8 and trying to run the 'Blink' program
Arduino 1.0.5 Software
I have chosen Arduino Uno as board type
My Serial port is COM3

When I try to upload a program I get the error

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

I have disabled bluetooth as well.

Please let me know if my board selection is correct

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the "freeduino board, v0.1. ATMega 328" doesn't equal the "Arduino Uno", but the "Arduino Duemilanowe w/ Atmega 328". So, go to Tools and select "Arduino Duemilanowe w/ Atmega 328".

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=201710.msg1486452#msg1486452

Another reason it might fail is because your driver wasn't installed correctly. In this case reinstall your driver.

Answer (score 0):

Freeduino should run with Uno setup. However if your controller does not have a bootloader, if you serial connection is wrong or if the controller is not running at all you will get the same error.

Comment: How do I detemine which of these it is ?

Comment: If you do not know if you have bootloader on the chip then you are in bad luck. Step 1 would be to get an ISP or another Arduino as ISP and figure this one out.

If it might be the serial connection --> use another Arduino and compare the results.

If you have only a self soldered freeduino kit, no experience and no tools you are in a very bad position.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this error when the COMn port is not available or defined.  A com port can become not effective when you just unplug the board/USB cable.

When you re-plug the USB cable into the PC, then in the Arduino IDE define the correct port and try compiling/reloading the program.

On my Windows/XP Pro machine, the Arduino uses COM5, but lists COM4 and COM5 as available choices.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My board was working all perfectly without any error and suddenly it threw this error. After much testing, I unplug the board from the USB port and plugged into another USB port (in the PC) and it all worked perfectly !

Of course that required changing the Serial Port number from Arduino -> Tools > Serial Port

My board is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error, nothing worked. Tried almost every option mentioned.

But the solution for me was simple. I have Windows 7 64-bit.

First remove all drivers and everything wat looks likes al (virtual) USB to COM port driver.

Reboot (its Windows)

Install the right drivers from the Arduino IDE drivers\ map, in my case the 64-bit drivers.

Go to [site for the FTDI Chip drivees](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) make the right choice for your OS and install.

Reboot (not asked but he its Windows)

Then I connected the Arduino en tried to upload the Blink-sketch.
And everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error so i change the serial port to COM1 to COM4, and I am using windows 7 
so go to tool->serial port->change COM1 to COM4 
If that didnt worked try to change board from Arduino uno to Duemilanove.
Hope this help you.....